# How to read trained data file in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to make face recognition service using AWS Lambda.
I want to deploy .zip file including trained data file. 
But, AWS Lambda don't deploy it because of its size.
So, I change the way. Upload trained data file to S3 and use it.
But, I don't know how to do it.
Could you tell me the way to read trained data file in S3, in AWS Lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the data in S3, you can copy the file from S3 into lambda. Lambda provides 512 MB of storage in the tmp folder that is writable at run-time.

```
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
If I download the trained data every time run a lambda function, is there any problem with the speed or aws fee?

Comment: Depending on how long it takes, you can attempt to download the the model outside of the event handler, this operation may be processed for free up to 10 seconds. Then it will be available for the first invocation and all subsequent invocations.   There will still be transfer fees from S3. What is the size of the data?

Comment: The size of the data want to use is 95MB.

And, I don't understand "Then it will be available for the first invocation and all subsequent invocation". 
Please, Could you elaborate this part?

Comment: By default lambda invokes the lambda_handler() function. This is known as the invocation.  Variables and code in the global variable space are not executed during each invocation, but are invoked once when the container is created. For example the import statements at the top of your code only executes one time as the container is invoked, not each time the lambda function is invoked. If you place your copy from S3 code outside of the lambd_handler()  and it executes in less than 10 seconds, you will not be charged for this. If the code takes longer than 10 seconds, it could cause errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Fortunately, the result to put download code in the global variable space works out without any problems. It was very helpful!! Thank you again